# Three20 app store rejection (UITouch) - removed offending code, Release build but exists in binary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, three20

I know that there are a lot of posts in about Three20 app store rejections due to private UITouch variables and I've read them all but I still haven't been able to solve the problem:

The non-public APIs that are included in your application are the 
following undocumented private UITouch instance variables: 
UITouch._locationInWindow 
UITouch._phase 
UITouch._previousLocationInWindow 
UITouch._tapCount 
UITouch._timestamp 
UITouch._touchFlags 
UITouch._view 
UITouch._window

Steps I've taken: 
1. Removed offending code from Three20UI.xcodeproj 
2. Release build

However, when I do a simple grep _phase libThree20UI.a (the resulting binary) I still get the result "libThree20UI.a matches". Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rather long thread about this [over here](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/c442af6e39a918b0?fwc=1).   That seems to be from nearly 2 years ago.  Has Three20 not been updated in the interim to remove the offending symbol use?

Make sure you build totally from clean;  nuke your objects, if you need.

Comment: I think a new branch was made removing the code that uses private APIs.

Comment: Thanks guys. Could you by any chance post a link to the branch that doesn't use the private APIs?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this rejection is caused by either uploading a Debug version of your app or by having a variable called DEBUG in your code. If you are using the latest version of three20 all the private calls have been removed for quite some time now

Comment: Right. Turns out that XCode was building debug builds EVEN after I set it to Release. Something got messed up in the .pbxproj file. Created a new project, dragged the files over, and it seems to be fine now.